# IntelliJ and Ruby plugin: Won't load

Tags: ruby, plugins, intellij-idea

I'm trying to enable Ruby via the plugin manager, and I receive the following error:

```
Plugin "Ruby" won't be able to load because required plugin "com.intellij.modules.ultimate" is disabled.
```

I'm using the latest community edition. What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby plugin is only for the ultimate versión.

So the options are, IntelliJ Ultimate version or RubyMine also from JetBrains